# XMLDataVariable formed with expression at run-time?

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I'm trying to use a xml source in a simple data flow task, by supplying the path to the xml file in a combination of project and package parameters.

This works fantastically with the XSD file of the xml source, by going into the expressions of the data flow task, choosing the [XML TASK].[XMLSchemaDefinition] and setting it to

```
@[$Project::XSD_ROOT]+ "\\" + @[$Package::XSD_Filename]
```

This loads the schema, so why can't I do the same thing with XMLData property?

I've set delay validation on both the data flow task and the xml source, and the access mode is set to 1 (tried it with 2 as well).

I just get "Unable to get the variable specified by the XMLDataVariable property"

Answer (score 0):

In the XML Source Editor change the Data access mode to: "XML file from variable".
Use expressions in the variable to determine the xml file name.

\Marco

Comment: I ended up going with this workaround. However, it's just a hassle, especially when you have many different XML sources, and you need a "temporary" variable, and expression task to set it up, when it should be possible to use an expression directly at the XMLData property.

Comment: If you have many XML sources consider a package for each source and a master package to execute the child packages. That has many advantage in flexibility, maintenance and  dividing the workload between your developers.